# Cropping with NY Studio Image Optimize Plugin

Tags: plugin-imageoptimize

Please forgive me if this is an idiot question.  How do I obtain 'crop' and 'scale' with Image Optimize??  I would like a page of equally sized images (height & width) which are cropped from the center. This is easy with a Craft transform .url('thumbs'), but what do I need to do to the following code to achieve this?

```
         {% set optimizedImages = works.artwork.one().fd_optimizedThumbs %}

         <img class="lazyload" src="{{ optimizedImages.placeholderImage() }}"
         data-srcset="{{ optimizedImages.srcset() }}"
         sizes="100vw" />
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the documentation for your plugin? You can [configure image variants and force specific aspect ratios](https://nystudio107.com/docs/image-optimize/using.html#using-the-optimized-images-field) in the field settings. If you don't want to configure those sizes for the entire field, but only in a specific place in your template, see dynamically [creating optimized image variants](https://nystudio107.com/docs/image-optimize/using.html#dynamically-creating-optimized-image-variants) in the documentation.

I haven't used this plugin before, but based on your example code and the documentation linked above, something like this should work:

```
{% set optimizedImages = craft.imageOptimize.createOptimizedImages(
    works.artwork.one(),
    [
        {
            'width': 200,
            'useAspectRatio': true,
            'aspectRatioX': 1.0,
            'aspectRatioY': 1.0,
            'retinaSizes': ['1'],
            'quality': 82,
            'format': 'jpg',
        },
    ]
) %}
```

Comment: Hi MoritzLost, Thanks for your reply.  I read that creating variants in the template would slow things down.  I have read the docs but I was struggling to find how it was done in field settings.  I have now realised it's possible to have multiple Image Optimize field types for different jobs (thumbnails, natural...) on the same page.  Once I discovered this I got it working.

Comment: @Martin Glad I could help! If your issue is solved, would you mind marking my answer as accepted? Thanks.